# IC Cube Reporting: Fire events from an Embedded Report

Tags: iccube-reporting

I am using an embedded report widget, and a select control widget that opens report A and report B in this embedded report.

- Is there a possibility to create an event (e.g. Click on Chart) inside report A which opens report B in the same embedded report widget?
- If yes, is it possible to also hand over a set of filters to report B?
  *

Here you can see an example:
[jump between embedded reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3QzU.png)

And another questions about navigation:

- Is there a possibility to open a report in a new browser tab, applying a set of filters to it?